# How to run uwsgi with gevent in async mode

Tags: python, uwsgi, gevent

I tried to run the following content

```
# aaa.py
def application(env, sr):
    import gevent
    print "A1"
    gevent.sleep(0)
    yield
    heavy_func()
    print "A2"
    gevent.sleep(0)
    yield
    heavy_func()
    print "A3"
    sr('200 OK', [('Content-Type','text/html')])
```

with

```
uwsgi --gevent 10 --http :9302 --enable-threads --module aaa
```

and when I simultaneously connected to the uwsgi, I got

```
A1
A2
A3
[pid: 21446|app: 0|req: 1/1] 10.0.1.103 () {36 vars in 632 bytes} [Fri Oct 17 12:07:40 2014] GET / => generated 0 bytes in 19036 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 1 headers in 44 bytes (5 switches on core 9)
A1
A2
A3
[pid: 21446|app: 0|req: 2/2] 10.0.1.103 () {34 vars in 552 bytes} [Fri Oct 17 12:07:59 2014] GET /favicon.ico => generated 0 bytes in 18733 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 1 headers in 44 bytes (5 switches on core 9)
A1
A2
A3
[pid: 21446|app: 0|req: 3/3] 10.0.1.103 () {36 vars in 632 bytes} [Fri Oct 17 12:08:56 2014] GET / => generated 0 bytes in 20247 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 1 headers in 44 bytes (5 switches on core 9)
A1
A2
A3
[pid: 21446|app: 0|req: 4/4] 10.0.1.103 () {36 vars in 666 bytes} [Fri Oct 17 12:09:16 2014] GET /availability/ping => generated 0 bytes in 18449 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 1 headers in 44 bytes (5 switches on core 9)
A1
A2
A3
[pid: 21446|app: 0|req: 5/5] 10.0.1.103 () {34 vars in 552 bytes} [Fri Oct 17 12:09:34 2014] GET /favicon.ico => generated 0 bytes in 24794 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 1 headers in 44 bytes (5 switches on core 9)
```

The logs shows that the uwsgi handle requests sequentially. What am I missing? Should
"gevent.sleep(0)" or "yield" change the context and handle the other requests also?

Comment: you do not need to yield in the WSGI callable, when you call the gevent api the greenlet is switched automatically. By the way, how you are testing it ?

Comment: Without yield it doesn't work also. I just tested by opening in multiple tabs in the browser.

Comment: you cannot test in this way, browsers generally do not open more than 2 concurrent connections. Use curl or similar